# Как разрешить использование кириллицы при создании пользователя в UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Использую стандартный механизм создания пользователя UserManager.Create. Заказчик хочет, чтобы в имени можно было использовать кириллицу. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

В MS Identity 2.0 (актуальном в данный момент времени) имя пользователя это строка. Строки в .NET по умолчанию UNICODE. В БД в таблице AspNetUsers данные хранятся также в UNICODE. Автогенерируемый код, юзающий Identity, использует в качестве имени пользователя введенный email. Но ведь Вы можете легко переписать соответствующие места, и использовать в качестве имени пользователя все что душа пожелает.

Всего лишь немного поправить стандартные формы и передать нужные параметры методу `ApplicationUserManager.Create()`